# Team tracking in between android apps

Tags: android

I want to develop an android app through which each member of a team should be able to see the movement of each other constantly. I am not sure how to connect them this way. It is easy to locate own phone and do whatever u want to do. but when it comes to sharing it is getting complex and I dont know from where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You will want a central server that can accept each team member's current coordinates and then tell each device where the other team members are.